# Conditions for ad-hoc distribution

Tags: iphone, ipad, ad-hoc-distribution

When I want to have someone help me out test or review an iPhone(iPod-touch or iPad) application. Is is enough to get her/his UDID and then make a build so that she/he can run the application on her/his device? Or are there other conditions?

In other words is it sufficient that this person has a device and is willing to give me the UDID to help me out, or should also that person be registered as a developer or something similar?
Which in that case would make the research of collabortors of course more complicated.

Thanks for any indication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UDID is enough for distributing the app.
You need to add this device UDID into the Devices section
Update the provisioning profile.
If you want to let him/her test it remotely, you need to upload it to some test distribution channel like TestFlight or diawi.com
For TestFlight you need to build the IPA but for diawi.com just build the .app and zip it with the provisioning and you are good to go. The tester later can simple enter the generated link from diawi.com on the device to install it.

Answer (score 3):

The UDID is enough. You have to add this device to your devices list on developer.apple.com and include it in a provisioning profile.

I would recommend you to check out [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) for beta distribution.
This makes the whole process much easier.